# How to install Smook Plug in Jboss Fuse IDE

Tags: fuseesb, jbossfuse, smooks

I need to use Smooks for data mapping in Jboss Fuse IDE. I couldn't find any smooks plugin for Jboss fuse IDE. Since Smooks is a jboss tool, It should be embedded in Fuse IDE. Can anyone please tell me how to install Smooks in Fuse IDE or any other tools that we can use in Fuse to do data mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Eclipse_IDE, it says the following:

> NOTE: The Smooks Editor is no longer part of JBoss Tools

Also, at https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossTools-SmooksEditor, there's been this comment by Brian Fitzpatrick since February 2012:

> Unfortunately due to a lack of resources, the Smooks tooling won't be updated any time soon I'm afraid.

This would suggest that we're stuck with editing the configuration files directly.